# Segue on Swipe on last page of UIPageView

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `PageViewController` with 3 pages. I want to segue away from `PageViewController` to `AnotherViewController` when user swipes from right to left on the last page. I cant figure out how to do it.

The only trigger for swipe is

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> UIViewController?
```

and looking for `index == 3` and then perform the segue BUT `index == 3` never reaches because there is no 4th page? What am I missing?

Comment: hello there. Have you tried ctrl dragging from the storyboard? or you want to do it via code?

Comment: i already have the segue setup in IB. now need to know where to performsegue in code to accomplish the question

Comment: Add your own gesture recognizer, and in the action check if the current VC is 2, and perform the segue if it is..

Comment: @Jay yeah that is one way, I was hoping to find a simpler solution

Comment: Add a 4th dummy VC, and check for index ==3 in viewControllerAtIndex? Not sure if this will work but it may.. Anyway, a gesture recognizer is not hard or complex to do.

Comment: @Jay 4th dummy idea is what I had implemented already. As you would agree, it is not the neatest of the solutions and I cant believe that this such a common requirement is not something readily available in xcode.

Comment: @Jay, you want to add yours as an answer and I will select it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no index 3. The last index is 2. Because it starts from 0 - 1 -2.